# Why the download speed of sFTP (by JSch) slowed down as time went on?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I meet an very stange issue when using JSch to do sFTP download.
When my program start up, it can download a file (about 2G) in 20 seconds;
After one day, the download time increases to about one minute;
After four or five days, the downlaod time increases to about five minutes;
If I restarted my program, it can download the file in 20 seconds.
When my program downloads slowly, other program can download in a normal speed.
With wireshark log, you can find RTT increases as time went on.

Other backgroud:
OS: CentOS 6.8
JRE: 1.8
JSch: 0.1.51 and 0.1.54

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Memory-leak? JVM too busy constantly running GC?

Comment: I have checked, GC is not invoked during the whole process.

Comment: You have given the Java process more memory than you physically have in your machine, so your process keeps swapping to disk and in and out of memory? Since your say that there is no GC, this is more likely.

Comment: I have checked, swap has never been used, and the allocated memory is less than physical memory.